# Horizontal scroller bar doesn't show in jtable. How to make the columns stop shrinking?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I am adding a **JScrollPane** to my **JTable** along with 
`HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` and  `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`.
And also setting **JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF**.  But when I add bunch of columns the names of the columns don't  show properly, they shrink to fit the table. And the horiztal scroller doesn't show.

here is the code and a picture of how it looks:

```
tableForDay1 = new JTable();
tableForDay1.setBounds(0, 619, 1337, -619);
tableForDay1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
tableForDay1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

JScrollPane scrollBar1 = new JScrollPane (tableForDay1, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollBar1.setVisible(true);
day1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(day1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
createColumns(tableForDay1);
```

here are the columns I add: (I pass the table as a parameter)

```
private void createColumns(JTable table)
{
    //get table model
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    table.setModel(tableModel);
    tableModel.addColumn("אזור");
    tableModel.addColumn("מוביל");
    tableModel.addColumn("ת.ה");
    tableModel.addColumn("מ.ה");
    tableModel.addColumn("קוד מוצר");
    tableModel.addColumn("יישוב");
    tableModel.addColumn("שעת תאום");
    tableModel.addColumn("תוספות למוצר");
    tableModel.addColumn("כתובת");
    tableModel.addColumn("קומה");
    tableModel.addColumn("דירה");
    tableModel.addColumn("שם הלקוח");
    tableModel.addColumn("תאור מוצר");
    tableModel.addColumn("פלאפון");
    tableModel.addColumn("אישר קשר נוסף");
    tableModel.addColumn("פירוט מחיר");
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 27));

    String[]row = { "something", "something", "something", "something" , 
            "something" , "something" , "something" , "something", "something", 
            "something", "something" , "something" , "something" , "something" };

    tableModel.addRow(row);
}
```

**here is the picture: Names of the columns don't show properly , and columns not alligned**

[image: Names of the columns don't show properly , and columns not alligned]

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(*insert your width here*);
```

You will have to do this for every Column.

Comment: also how can I add the values of the rows from right to left to match the columns?( the columns are inserted from right to left in the picture as you can see but the calues from left to right)

Comment: im sorry but i cant help you there. i tried it by makeing my list going right to left like you did with setting the ComponentOrientation to RIGHT_TO_LEFT and it works perfektly fine.